# Writing to file using TPL with ConcurrentQueue

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, task-parallel-library

Here is a sample code to explain the approach I am going for.

```
public class LogWriter
{
    #region Private Members

    // If writer is not static class, still need to keep single message list; same for other members
    private static ConcurrentQueue<string> _logMessages = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
    private static object locker = new object();
    private static bool _stopAfterCurrentQueue = false;
    private static bool _discardQueueAndStop = false;

    private static CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    #endregion

    public void Write(string text)
    {
        if (!_stopAfterCurrentQueue && !_discardQueueAndStop)
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
           {
               _logMessages.Enqueue(text);

           });

            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                while (!_logMessages.IsEmpty)
                {
                    foreach (var item in _logMessages)
                    {

                        _logMessages.TryDequeue(out string current);
                        lock (locker)
                        {
                            // Will be replaced by StreamWriter
                            File.AppendAllText("Log_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMMdd") + ".txt", current + Environment.NewLine);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, _tokenSource.Token);
        }
    }

    public void ProcessCurrentAndStop()
    {
        // Only stops accepting new messages, will process the current queue
        _stopAfterCurrentQueue = true;
    }

    public void DiscardQueueAndStop()
    {
        // Cancels subsequent Enqueue
        _tokenSource.Cancel();

        // No more writing even if there is something in the queue
        _discardQueueAndStop = true;
    }

    public void RestartLogging()
    {
        _stopAfterCurrentQueue = false;
        _discardQueueAndStop = false;

        _tokenSource.Dispose();
        _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    }
}
```

The idea is to write to file in asynchronous way. I am trying to make it thread safe as well. There is not much to process here except to write message to a file.

I would like to understand what could be potential issues with this approach and also if it would be better to keep class `static`.

Comment: You are not checking the cancellation token.

Answer (score 2):

Let’s try to get rid of `ConcurrentQueue`. And `Task.Run` – those are expensive ones. It also makes sense to use async file access – which is a way more lightweight.

```
public class LogWriter
{
    public static LogWriter Instance = new LogWriter();

    LogWriter()
    {
        Enabled = true;
        Cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Task = Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    bool Enabled { get; set; }
    CancellationTokenSource Cts { get; set; } 
    Task Task { get; set; }
    string Path => $"Log_{DateTime.Now:yyyyMMMdd}.txt";

    public void Start() => Enabled = true;

    public void Stop(bool discard = false)
    {
        Enabled = false;
        if (discard)
        {
            Cts.Cancel();
            Cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            Task = Task.ContinueWith(t => { });
        }
    }

    public void Write(string line) =>
        Write(line, Path, Cts.Token);

    void Write(string line, string path, CancellationToken token)
    {
        if (Enabled)
            lock(Task)
                Task = Task.ContinueWithAsync(
                    t => AppendAllTextAsync(path, line + NewLine, token),
                    token);
    }        
}
```

Where missing part would be:

```
static class AsyncContinuations
{
    public static async Task ContinueWithAsync(this Task task, Func<Task, Task> continuationFunction, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await task;
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        await continuationFunction(task);
    }
}
```

Comment: @t3chb0t – how do you like this scheduling mechanism. I could not believe it – Microsoft TPL ContinueWith() does not support async actions! And C# does not allow a sleek overload for that…

Comment: I first have to reformat it to something that my brain can deal with :-P There are too many _missing_ `{}` and since I really dislike python I have to re-add them ;-) I'm also wondering that I didn't get any notification from SE, I found your comment by accident :-o

Comment: @t3chb0t Have you ever witnessed a grammar reform in a human language? Yep, that one is a real pain to the eyes :)  Have a look at F# - around 4 times less noise, you could quickly become addicted. Old C# style is so dramatically outdated.... It is just like a modern day Pascal :)

Comment: This is **NOT** thread-safe. 1. Thread A locks on `Task`(id 0). Thread B locks on `Task`(id 0) and blocks. Thread A assigns `Task` a new Task(id 1). Thread C locks on `Task`(id 1). Thread A releases lock on Task(id 0). Thread B and C can now both enter the critical section.

Comment: It may look and run fine but that's only because `AppendAllTextAsync` (and siblings) don't defer execution unless the write size exceeds the write buffer (4KiB). So it's not thread-safe and it's not async (fire and forget/continue) for small writes.

Comment: Try running `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Exception); Parallel.For(0, 1_000, i => LogWriter.Instance.Write(new string(' ', 4100)));`. Then try changing 4100 to 2000 and observe it never goes parallel.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would build up the append and then just take the Lock once.  Write all at once is going to be more efficient.

```
public static void WriteTask(string text)
{
    if (!_stopAfterCurrentQueue && !_discardQueueAndStop  && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
    {
        _logMessages.Enqueue(text);

        List<string> lString = new List<string>();
        string current;
        while (_logMessages.TryDequeue(out current))
        {
            lString.Add(current);
        }

        lock (locker)
        {
            File.AppendAllLines("Log_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMMdd") + ".txt", lString);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `Parallel.Invoke()` is  better than `Task.Run()`. `Parallel.Invoke()` is best performance wise for parallel task also interface object is not Disposed after Completed  HTTP request. it's working as background task.

```
public class LogWriter
{
    #region Private Members

    // If writer is not static class, still need to keep single message list; same for other members
    private static ConcurrentQueue<string> _logMessages = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
    private static object locker = new object();
    private static bool _stopAfterCurrentQueue = false;
    private static bool _discardQueueAndStop = false;

    private static CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    private static readonly SemaphoreSlim _messageEnqueuedSignal = new SemaphoreSlim(0);
    #endregion

    public static void Write(string text)
    {

        if (!_tokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            if (!_stopAfterCurrentQueue && !_discardQueueAndStop)
            {
                Parallel.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    _logMessages.Enqueue(text);
                    _messageEnqueuedSignal.Release();
                });

                Parallel.Invoke( async () =>
                    {
                        await _messageEnqueuedSignal.WaitAsync(_tokenSource.Token);
                        while (!_logMessages.IsEmpty)
                        {
                            foreach (var item in _logMessages)
                            {

                                _logMessages.TryDequeue(out string current);
                                lock (locker)
                                {
                                // Will be replaced by StreamWriter
                                File.AppendAllText("Log_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMMdd") + ".txt", current + Environment.NewLine);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
            }
        }
    }

    public void ProcessCurrentAndStop()
    {
        // Only stops accepting new messages, will process the current queue
        _stopAfterCurrentQueue = true;
    }

    public void DiscardQueueAndStop()
    {
        // Cancels subsequent Enqueue
        _tokenSource.Cancel();

        // No more writing even if there is something in the queue
        _discardQueueAndStop = true;
    }

    public void RestartLogging()
    {
        _stopAfterCurrentQueue = false;
        _discardQueueAndStop = false;

        _tokenSource.Dispose();
        _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    }
}
```